# (Windows phone 8.1) Create rounded image button at windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, imagebutton

I want to create a image button with corner radius 20.0 in windows phone 8.1, but I can not find any solution , anyone can suggest me a way to do this ?

The button look like that :

[image: the button look like that]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Border element

```
<Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="20"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
    <Button  BorderThickness="0" Click="Button_Click"  >
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/cart.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    </Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<Button  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,636,0,0" >
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="#6BA92A" Background="#6BA92A" CornerRadius="20,20,20,20" BorderThickness="2">
                <Button   Content="Add to cart"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          Height="65"
                          Width="348"
                          FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                          BorderBrush="#6BA92A">
                </Button>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved that issue, here is my code :

```
<Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Margin="20,0,20,20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="50" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" > <Rectangle.Fill>
<ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"  ImageSource="/Assets/images/add_cart_btn_bg.png"/>
 </Rectangle.Fill> </Rectangle>
```